# Assistance Converting Varchar mmddyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in SQL

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2012

I'm working with a customer that has a field that is varchar and they use it for entering a date. I know that it's bad practice, but it's what I have to work with. Anyway, I'm hoping they always enter mmddyyyy i.e. '03152016' but they might enter '31516'. Is there any way to convert this to mm/dd/yyyy?

I've tried cast. I've tried convert. I've tried a temp table. Seems that I'm doomed to always get some kind of conversion error of an out-of-range value or failure. The following are some examples of the items I've tried. Any tips on how I might get this working.

```
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), [TheirField], 101) FROM Table
 OR
 CREATE TABLE #temp
 (FormattedDate datetime)
 Insert into #temp
 SELECT [TheirField] FROM Table
 OR
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),CAST([TheirField] as datetime),101) FROM Table
```

Comment: How would you like to translate `11116` as `01-11-2016` or `11-01-2016`?

Answer (score 0):

I would say first, lets pad the front side with a zero (0), to make sure that we have a full 6, 8, character length value.  Whether it is in the stored data or not, consider a final data validation step before dealing with it.

There are two approaches to this quandry.  I will take the long way around, so you see the granular steps.  There will always be a better way to skin the cat, but knowing the incremental steps will help provide you the necessary steps that need to be performed.

- Upgrade 6 character length to 8 character length (Suggested, as it creates a standard format length to deal with)

> ```
> declare @val varchar(15) = '11116'
> declare @yr varchar(4), @mn varchar(2), @day varchar(2)
>
> -- First check to see if SQL recognizes the format; not full-proof just a guage ;)
> select ISDATE(@val)
>
> -- Pad the month with a preceeding zero (0)
> select @val = right('0' + @val, 6)
>
> select @val 
>
> -- Extract the date components
> select @yr = '20' + right(@val, 2)
>   , @mn = left(@val, 2)
>   , @day = SUBSTRING(@val, 3, 2)
>
> select @yr, @mn, @day 
>
> -- Reconstitute the date in your preferred format
> select @mn + '/' + @day + '/' + @yr
> ```

- Handle them, 6 and 8 length, individually.  Variation of the above steps shown.